# How to loop through a column in Python?

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

I **have** seen answers about this question but no one helped me. Some used *numpy*, and some people answered using other platforms that help Python to be simpler. I don't want these type of things, I want with the simple Python without importing libraries or anything more.

Let's say: I would want to do a method that checks if there's at least one column in the 2D array that the column has the same values.
For example:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
```

Sending `arr` to my method would return `True` because in the third column there is in each term the number 3.

How would I write this method? How do I loop through each column in the 2D array?

Comment: You will have to write an algorithm that loops over rows.

Answer (score 13):

## Loop through column

> How do I loop through each column in the 2D array?

In order to loop through each column just loop through the transposed matrix [(a transposed matrix is just a new matrix where the rows of original matrix are now columns and vice-versa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

```
# zip(*matrix) generates a transposed version of your matrix
for column in zip(*matrix): 
    do_something(column)
```

## An answer to your proposed problem/example

> I would want to do a method that checks if there's at least one column
>   in the 2D array that the column has the same values

General method:

```
def check(matrix):
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        if column[1:] == column[:-1]:
            return True
    return False
```

One-liner:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
any([x[1:] == x[:-1] for x in zip(*arr)])
```

Explanation:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
# transpose the matrix
transposed = zip(*arr) # transposed = [(2, 4, 1), (0, 2, 0), (3, 3, 3)]
# x[1:] == x[:-1] is a trick.
# It checks if the subarrays {one of them by removing the first element (x[1:])
# and the other one by removing the last element (x[:-1])} are equals.
# They will be identical if all the elements are equal. 
equals = [x[1:] == x[:-1] for x in transposed] # equals = [False, False, True]
# verify if at least one element of 'equals' is True
any(equals) # True
```

### Update 01

@BenC wrote:

> "You could also skip the [] around the list comprehension so that any
>   just gets a generator that can be stopped early once/if it returns
>   false"

so:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
any(x[1:] == x[:-1] for x in zip(*arr))
```

### Update 02

You could also use sets (merged with the answer of @HelloV).

One-liner:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
any(len(set(x))==1 for x in zip(*arr))
```

General method:

```
def check(matrix):
    for column in zip(*matrix):
        if len(set(column)) == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

A set does not have repeated elements, so if you transform a list into a set `set(x)` any duplicated element goes away, so, if all elements are equals, the lenght of resulting set is equal to one `len(set(x))==1`.

Comment: You could also skip the `[]` around the list comprehension so that `any` just gets a generator that can be stopped early once/if it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example, without adding the complexity of list comprehensions and the zip function is the following:

```
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,2]]

def check_column_equals_index(colum):
    for row in arr:
        if row[colum-1] != colum:
            return False
    return True

print check_column_equals_index(3)
```

which will output True if the 3th column is equal to 3 for every row.

Nonetheless, as you might have read in some other related discussions, it might be worth considering to use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) or [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: Here are you sending the array column to the method? I want to loop a 2D array without needing to put it on a variable before.

Comment: The method is just to show you how a function can be defined that uses the 2D array. You do not necessarily write a function for it, but it might be a good idea. The column parameter in the example is just the column number that you want to check. In your question you explained the example of column 3, which needed to be 3. This is how you could do that. In order to check all columns, you will also have to iterate over the columns with an additional `for column in row:` statement. Or you might use the more advanced approach as described by @iuridiniz

Answer (score 0):

```
1 in [len(set(i)) for i in zip(*arr)]
```

Comment: you could use just: `any(len(set(i))==1 for i in zip(*arr))`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through a column in 2D list and no imports? How about  extract columns elements to auxiliary list and then compare among themselves. You can control the process in this synoptical function:

```
def checkcolumn(colnum, arrex=[]):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arrex.append(arr[i][colnum])

    if arrex.count(arrex[0]) == len(arrex):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print checkcolumn(1)
```

Seems easiest and pretty didactic to me. Other ways of comparing elements in column can be found at:  https://www.csestack.org/python-check-if-all-elements-in-list-are-same/

Answer (score 0):

I came here to look at these solutions, but I felt like it didn't really answer the question -- how do you loop through columns without some library in Python?  I assume you mean loop by columns (as in going left to right to view a 2D matrix).

In a 2D array, looping through each index means viewing a new row with its own inner array.

If you create a loop over this inner array loop, then each time you traverse an inner array from the outer array - you can view the inner array with the current outer array index (essentially a column).

The inner loop will loop through "columns" until finished, then the outer loop increments to the next index, and again with the inner loop we visit all columns at this index until finished; and so on -- until the outer loop is done too.

Note: You will need to keep track of how many columns to visit with your outer loop, one way to do this is to get the length of the first inner array in your 2D array and assume that all subsequent inner arrays have the same length.  So this solution will work for your problem since all your inner arrays have the same length.

Code example:

```py
arr = [[2,0,3],[4,2,3],[1,0,3]]
# assumes that all other inner rows visited will be same length.
rowsize = len(arr[0]) 

for i in range(0, len(rowsize)):
  for row in arr:
    print(row[i])
```

Expected Output:

```sh
2
4
1
0
2
0
3
3
3
```

Feel free to modify this to suit your method for testing.  Should be easy to check if 3 appears again in the same column.