# Get each column in a 3x4 matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I am an absolute newb to python, and i am having trouble understanding how exactly you would be able to iterate through a 2D array to get the columns.

I have a 3x4 matrix that looks something like this:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9],
 [2, 4, 5, 6]]
```

The code that I have tried on python looks something like this:

```
def get_column(row, row1, row2):
    get_total = 0
    # i = 0
    # j = 0
    # row = list()
    # end = " "
    m = []
    col_count = 0
    # i is the number of lists in the super list
    # so we need go two_dim[i]
    two_dim = [[row], [row1], [row2]]
    for i in range(len(two_dim)):
        print(two_dim[i])
        for j in range(len(two_dim[i])):
            print(two_dim[i][j])
            for k in range(len(two_dim[j])):

                first_column = two_dim[i][j]
                # print(first_column, end=" ")
                col_count += 1
    # print(two_dim[i][j][2])
    # print(second_column, end=" ")
    # second_column = row1[j][j+1]
    # third_column = row2[k][k+2]
```

I have been racking my brain for quite a while trying to figure out how exactly I would be able to iterate over the matrix to get the columns.

I was only able to get the first column, but havent been able to print any of the other 3 columns.

I would appreciate it so much if someone could guide me in the right direction!

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I would like to do it programatically than use a library. But if its not feasible then libraries would work!

Thank you so much!

Comment: `zip(*list_of_lists)` will transpose the matrix and allow you to iterate over columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a column in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386476/how-to-loop-through-a-column-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to achieve your result.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 6]])
for col in df.columns:
  print list(df[col])

#Output
[2, 6, 2]
[3, 7, 4]
[4, 8, 5]
[5, 9, 6]
```

Alternatively, you can use @wwii solutions -

```py
zip(*list_of_lists)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, is there any way I can achieve this programmatically rather than use pandas?

Comment: You can use @wwii solution provided in comments

Answer (score 0):

use two for loop or list comprehension

```
a = [[2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [2, 4, 5, 6]]
transpose_a = [[a[column][row]for column in range(len(a))]for row in range(len(a[0]))]
for col in transpose_a:
    print(col)
```